# Number of $\sigma$  -Algebra on the finite set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ is a nonempty set with $m$ members . How many $\sigma$ -algebra can we make on this set?

Comment: I think number of $\sigma$-algebra is less than $2^{n}$ where $n$ is the number of $X$.

Comment: @Alizter I see you opened a bounty because the question has not received enough attention. Do you want my answer to be more detailed?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I think that would be a good idea. I also think that this question is applicable to a greater audience so perhaps some simpler notation and explanation may be in order. Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 29):

**Short answer.** You can make as much $\sigma$-algebras as partitions on $X$.

**Formal verification.** Let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of all the algebras over $X$, and let $\Pi$ be all the partitions of $X$ (which consist of non-empty sets). There is a bijective correspondence between $\mathcal A$ and $\Pi$. Indeed, for a partition $P\in \Pi$, consider $\mathfrak A_{\Pi}$ the algebra generated by $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$, the elements of $P$, i.e. $\mathfrak A_{\Pi}$ consists of the set $\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j$, where $J\subset \{1,\ldots,k\}$. To see that this correspondence is bijective, given an 
algebra $\mathfrak A$, you can define for all $x\in X$ the set $A_x:=\bigcap_{A\in \mathfrak A,x\in A}A$ (it is a finite intersection), and that will give you a unique partition.

Indeed, define the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $A_x=A_y$. It gives a partition, and it is the unique one. If $P=\{S_1,\ldots,S_m\}$ works, then $A_x=S_{i(x)}$ for some $i(x)$, and you can check that this partition consists of the equivalence classes of $\sim$.

So the problem is to enumerate the number of partitions of a set which has $m$ elements. You will have to use [Bell's numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: Why is this correspondence bijective?

Comment: I've added the details.

Comment: What about when X is countably infinite?  Does it still work?  That intersection of elements of the sigma-algebra would no longer be finite, correct?

Comment: How may different probability measures one can give to a given finite $\sigma$-algebra?