# Number of sigma algebras for set with 4 elements

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to watch out for sigma algebras that belong to the set $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. I found 15(now with the new set even more) of them. I was wondering whether there is some nice proof how to see that there are no more of them? The problem is, that I would try to prove this by looking at a lot of different cases, how a new sigma-algebra would have to look like and prove then that it already is the whole set. Does anybody here have a better idea?

only the set and the empty one//
the set of all subsets//
4 sets, where you take the set, the empty one and one element with its complement.//
3 sets with the empty one, the set itself and a set containing two elements and its complement.//
EDIT:
I have even found 6 of another type that are possible, just like: $\Sigma = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\emptyset,X\}$

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: how did you find that there are only $9$??

Comment: (in general, nontrivial) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143796/number-of-sigma-algebra-on-the-finite-set

Comment: well I found 9 of them, just by writing them down.

Comment: There should actually be $15$ of them. Check out the answer in the link.

Comment: One approach is just to note that $\sigma \subset 2^X$ and that $\left|2^X\right|=16$, so you can easily check which subsets are valid algebras and which are not. This approach is obviously not a good one as the size of the set $X$ grows, but it is definitely a sure way to convince yourself in this case.

Comment: How??? I mean how did you write??? as there are only $9$, it would be better if you can write them here...

Comment: @par well, this is not a good way, because we need to look at the algebras and this means, that we do not have to check 16 sets, but actually $2^16$. This makes this approach a rather stupid one(even in this case)

Comment: I have "casually" explained how they look like in the new paragraph

Comment: how much are you sure about "3 sets with the empty one, the set itself and a set containing two elements and its complement."

Comment: do you see one more or shall i write them down?

Comment: you actually wants to consider a set with $2$ elements from a set with $4$ elements... how many do you think there are.. I think it should be $4.3=12$... I don't know if i am wrong... I dont even want to say the upper bound is $16$ because, we are not considering only subsets but actually collection of subsets....

Comment: we have $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,4\}$ each one with its complement and which other sets shall we have?

Comment: Oh yes... you are correct... I was wrong..

Comment: no problem..thanks for your help

Comment: Doesn't the answer in the linked question solve your problem?

Comment: it would be okay, if i knew how to prove that the number of partitions is 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it suffices to count the number of partitions
of $X$ in nonempty parts. The number of partitions of a set $X$ of cardinality
$n$ in $k$ nonempty parts is denoted $\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\rbrace$. Those numbers are called [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Up to relabeling, a partition of $X$ into $k$ nonempty parts is the same thing as a surjection
$X \to \lbrace 1,2,\ldots ,k\rbrace$. Since there are $k!$ such relabelings, 
the number of such surjections is $k!\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\rbrace$.

Let $[k]$ denote the inetger interval  $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots ,k\rbrace$, $F(X,k)$ denote the set of all maps $X \to [k]$, and for a given set $A$, denote by $S(X,A)$ the set of all surjections $X \to A$. So 
$|S(X,A)|=|A|!\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ |A| \end{matrix}\right\rbrace$, and $F(X,k)$
is obviously partitioned by all the $S(X,A)$ for $A\subseteq [k]$. Since there are $\binom{k}{r}$ subsets of cardinality $r$ in $[k]$, we see that

$$
k^n=|F(X,k)|=\sum_{r=0}^k \binom{k}{r} r! \left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ r\end{matrix}\right\rbrace =
\sum_{r=0}^k \frac{k!}{(k-r)!}  \left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ r\end{matrix}\right\rbrace=
k! \left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ k\end{matrix}\right\rbrace+ \sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \frac{k!}{(k-r)!}  \left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ r\end{matrix}\right\rbrace
$$

and hence

$$
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix}\right\rbrace=
\frac{k^n}{k!}-\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \frac{\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ r\end{matrix}\right\rbrace}{(k-r)!} 
$$

Starting from the obvious $\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right\rbrace=1$,
we deduce successively that 
$$
\begin{array}{lclcl}
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ 2 \end{matrix}\right\rbrace &=& 
\frac{2^n}{2!}-
\frac{\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ 1\end{matrix}\right\rbrace}{1!}  &=&
2^{n-1}-1 \\
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ 3 \end{matrix}\right\rbrace &=& 
\frac{3^n}{6!}-
\frac{\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ 1\end{matrix}\right\rbrace}{2!}-
\frac{\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} n \\ 2\end{matrix}\right\rbrace}{1!}  &=&
\frac{3^{n-1}-1}{2}-(2^{n-1}-1) \\
\end{array}
$$

In your example $n=4$ and hence

$$
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} 4 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right\rbrace=1, \
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} 4 \\ 2\end{matrix}\right\rbrace=2^{4-1}-1=7, \
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} 4 \\ 3\end{matrix}\right\rbrace=\frac{3^{4-1}-1}{2}-(2^{4-1}-1)=6, \
\left\lbrace\begin{matrix} 4 \\ 4\end{matrix}\right\rbrace= 1
$$

So the total number of partitions you’re looking for is $1+7+6+1=15$.