# question about sigma field

Tags: measure-theory

How do you determine the σ-field and the Dynkin system in Ω={1,2,3,4}?

I know the smallest σ-field is {empty set, Ω}, and also I have worked out some others
{empty set, {1},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {2},{1,3,4},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {3},{1,2,4},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {4},{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {1,2},{3,4},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {1,3},{2,4},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {1,4},{2,3},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {2,3},{1,4},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {2,4},{1,3},{1,2,3,4}},
{empty set, {3,4},{1,2},{1,2,3,4}},
I know that there are others, but just don't know where to start. like what ideas should I follow in this question.

Comment: This may help- The cardinality of every $\sigma$-field is a power of two.

Comment: Yeah, but how many exactly are there if Ω={1,2,3,4}, I have found 20 already, but i have looked up on other website, it said should be 15. so really dont know how many are there...

Comment: You have listed some twice e.g. {empty,{1,2},{3,4},{1,2,3,4}} is the same as {empty,{3,4},{1,2},{1234}}. [The order in which the subsets are listed doesn't matter.]

Comment: @user133473 It is impossible to have 20 $\sigma$- fields, since the cardinality of the power set of $\Omega$ is only $2^4$, and this should be an upper bound for the number of $\sigma$-fields.

Comment: @coffeemath oh, I just realized... Thanks so much!

Comment: @Chazz Each $\sigma$-field is a particular kind of partition of $\Omega$, and aren't there more of these than there are subsets of it?

Comment: @Chazz Then how about the Dynkin System of  Ω={1,2,3,4}? Is it any sigma field is a Dynkin System?

Comment: @coffeemath By definition a sigma field of $\Omega$ is an element of its power set.

Comment: @Chazz Actually a Dynkin system for $\Omega$ is a subset, rather than an element, of its power set. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system

Comment: @user133473 Could you give a link, in response or (better) in the post, to the website where they only found 15 Dynkin systems for {1,2,3,4}? Because it seems to me there are quite a few more.

Comment: @coffeemath http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529771/number-of-sigma-algebras-for-set-with-4-elements?rq=1

Comment: @Chazz By definition an element of a power set of a set S is a subset of S, never a sigma-field on S.

Comment: @Did You are right, my mistake