# Is there a general way to count the number of sigma-algebras on a finite set?

Tags: measure-theory

I was asked a high-school question today which was merely asking the number of sigma-algebras on a set.

> Let $X$ be a set
>
> Let $S\triangleq \{\Sigma\subset P(X): \Sigma \text{ is a sigma-algebra on }X\}$.
>
> If $X$ is finite, what would be the cardinality of $S$?

The question i was asked was the case $|X|=3$. In this case $|S|=5$.

What would be the cardinality of $S$ in general? Is it possible to find this value via elementary function?

Comment: This was asked before, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143796/number-of-sigma-algebra-on-the-finite-set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sigma algebra on a finite set is uniquely determined by the minimal non-empty elements under inclusion. (Why?)

The minimal elements are pair-wise disjoint. (Why?)

The minimal elements must have the entire set as a union. (Why?)

So the minimal elements form a partition of the set.

Comment: The minimal elements are pair-wise disjoint. (Why?) Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Let $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subset\Sigma$ be the set of the minimal non-empty elements under inclusion. $A_i\cap A_j=X\setminus(X\setminus A_i\cup X\setminus A_j)\in\Sigma$ for any $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $A_i\cap A_j\neq\emptyset$ for some $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $i\neq j$, then $A_i\supsetneq A_i\cap A_j$ or $A_j\supsetneq A_i\cap A_j$ because $A_i\neq A_j$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $A_i\supsetneq A_i\cap A_j$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: The minimal elements must have the entire set as a union. (Why?) Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Let $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subset\Sigma$ be the set of the minimal non-empty elements under inclusion. Suppose $A_1\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_n\subsetneq X.$ Since $X$ is finite and $X\setminus (A_1\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_n)$ is not empty, there is a minimal non-empty element $B$ under inclusion such that $X\setminus (A_1\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_n)\supset B.$ Since $B\cap (A_1\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_n)=\emptyset$, $B\neq A_i$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}.$ This is a contradiction.

Comment: A sigma algebra on a finite set is uniquely determined by the minimal non-empty elements under inclusion. (Why?) Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Let $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subset\Sigma$ be the set of the minimal non-empty elements under inclusion.

Comment: Let $B$ be a non-empty element of $\Sigma.$ Since $X$ is finite and $B$ is not empty, there is $i_1\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $B\supset A_{i_1}.$ $B\setminus A_{i_1}\in\Sigma.$ If $B\setminus A_{i_1}\neq\emptyset$, then there is $i_2\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $(B\setminus A_{i_1})\supset A_{i_2}.$ $(B\setminus A_{i_1})\setminus A_{i_2}\in\Sigma.$ If we continue like this, finally $(\dots((B\setminus A_{i_1})\setminus A_{i_2})\dots\setminus A_{i_k})=\emptyset$ holds. So, $B=A_{i_1}\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_{i_k}.$

Comment: Let $\Sigma'$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ such that $\Sigma\neq\Sigma'$ and the set of the minimal non-empty elements of $\Sigma'$ under inclusion is $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}.$ Since $\Sigma\neq\Sigma'$, there is $B$ such that $B\in\Sigma$ but $B\notin\Sigma'$ or $B\in\Sigma'$ but $B\notin\Sigma.$ Without loss of generality, we can assume there is $B$ such that $B\in\Sigma$ but $B\notin\Sigma'$.

Comment: We can write $B=A_{i_1}\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_{i_k}$ since $B\in\Sigma$. Since $A_{i_1},\dots,A_{i_k}\in\Sigma'$ and $\Sigma'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $B=A_{i_1}\bigsqcup\dots\bigsqcup A_{i_k}\in\Sigma'.$ This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thomas Andrews, Thank you very much for your answer!