# How many $\sigma$-algebras on a $4$-element set $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How many $\sigma$-algebras on a set $X$ are there when the cardinality of $X$ is $4$?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? How many different collections of subsets of $X$ are there?

Comment: [For finite arbitrary cardinality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143796/number-of-sigma-algebra-on-the-finite-set?noredirect=1&lq=1).