# Smallest sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A_{\alpha}$ be subsets of $\Omega$ so that $\bigcup A_\alpha =\Omega$ and that $A_\alpha\cap A_\beta=\phi$ if $\alpha \ne \beta$. Let $S$ be the set of all $A_\alpha$'s. Then $\sigma(S)$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ containing $S$, consists of all sets that are countable unions of $A_\alpha$'s or complements of countable unions of $A_\alpha$'s.

I don't quite understand the $\sigma(S)$. Suppose $\Omega=\{1,2\}$ and $A_{1}=\{1\}$ and $A_{2}=\{2\}$ and so they are disjoint and the union is $\Omega$. What are some examples of the $\sigma$-algebras that contain $S$? What is this smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma (S)$?

Comment: By definition, $S$ is $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$

Comment: $S$ contains more than that. $S$ is (roughly) the collection of all partitions of $\Omega$, and there is another way of partitioning $\Omega$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Comment: So is $S$ like $\{ \phi,\{1\} , \{2\} \}$? because the $A_{\alpha}$'s are disjoint

Comment: Any $\sigma$-algebra must have $\varnothing$ and the entire set as members. In this case, the only $\sigma$-algebras on $\{1,2\}$ are $\{\varnothing, \{1,2\}\}$ and $\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$. $\sigma$-algebras on finite sets in general are discussed in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143796/number-of-sigma-algebra-on-the-finite-set